# Link Button and AJAX function

Tags: jquery, ajax, button

I have spent the past couple of days trying to get a button to work and for the life of me cant. The set up is:
HTML inside of a larger PHP function. This function is required as it produces results. A modal is called and the function's results are put inside of this modal. Next to the results is the button in question. When it is clicked, I need it to execute an AJAX script. Below are some things I have tried but failed:

ONCLICK METHOD
HTML

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' class='button' onclick='click' ><i class='icon fas fa-globe'></i>
```

AJAX/ JQUERY

```
function click(id){
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: my_ajax.ajax_url,
        data: { 
        action: 'waitlist_test2_update_function',
        tid : id
        },      
        success: function(data){
            if(data == 'updated'){
                jQuery('.tdid_'+id).text('Seated');
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

^^^^^ this produces no results. No errors, no logs no return to the console just nothing. The AJAX/JQUERY is stored in a separate .JS file along with the other AJAX calls for the page. The HTML as mentioned is inside a larger PHP function which works and I know this since it spits out the results along with the button's HTML.

Next I tried the JS listening method:

HTML

```
<button id="mybtn" href="javascript:void(0)" class="button" > <i class=" icon fas fa-globe"></i></button>
```

AJAX/ JQUERY

```
jquery(document).ready(function(){
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    let btnElm = document.querySelector("#mybtn");
    btnElm.addEventListener("click", function() {
      /* Do Something */
      alert('hallo world');
    });
});
});
```

Also tried:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    let btnElm = document.querySelector("#mybtn");
    btnElm.addEventListener("click", function() {
      /* Do Something */
      alert('hallo world');
    });
});
```

This produces no click and an error of

> Uncaught TypeError: btnElm is null
>  ...update_call.js:77
> EventListener.handleEvent* ...update_call.js:75

So I simplified and tried the same HTML with

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
document.getElementById("mybtn").innerHTML = "you clicked me"; 
});
```

^^^ no errors, no response, no reporting. I am totally lost as to how to get this connected. Ultimately I need the button  to call a function that I can then populate with JQUERY and AJAX

Also tried:

```
document.getElementById ("mybtn").addEventListener ("click", myFunction, false);
```

This gives me an error - document.getElementById(...) is null

And:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
document.getElementById("mybtn").innerHTML = "you clicked me"; 
});
```

produces
document.getElementById(...) is null

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#mybtn').click( function () {
        /*  ajax function */
    } );

});
```